# Large white space below footer showing on certain pages on iPhone actual device but not emulator in Chrome

Tags: html, css, iphone, jsp, safari

There is an issue in my website which I am not able to resolve at all. Basically, on just a few pages (not every page) where I include a common footer, there is a large white space below it. I am able to view the fix correctly on iPhone emulator in Chrome Dev Tools. However, when I run the page on an actual iPhone device Safari browser, there is a huge white space below the footer. I have tried all ends to fix this issue but I see no solution. Could anyone help?

Here is how I include the JSP:

```
<footer class="footer-container">
   <s:include value="/jsp/common/Footer.jsp" />
</footer>
```

Here is the CSS code for the footer container:

```
.footer-container {position:relative;}
.footer-container{height: 87px;}
```

Comment: a screenshot of the issue would help

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry but I cannot provide the screenshot from the organization network. Thats not allowed for me. However, I can describe it as a "huge" space beneath the footer thats not present on other pages. Do you suggest its a coding problem in the JSP or more of a CSS issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot suggest what it could be without more information

Comment: One more observation is that the space beneath the footer vanishes after about 5 minutes of staying on the same page. Could this be a Javascript source read issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found a solution to this issue. This will help you to solve similar issues on your mobile device.

Once, i added a css class as:

```
.navInActive
{                                                                      
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
-moz-transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
-ms-transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
-ms-transform:translate(0px, 0);
-o-transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
 transform:translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
 z-index: 0;-ms-transform:translate(0, 0);
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease;-ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease;transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

The issue was resolved. All those who face this issue on iPhone Safari could try it out and let me know.

Comment: where did you add this to?